# Are you eligible to work unrestricted in the country to which you are applying?

Tags: job-search, applications

This is a question during a prospective employer's application process.

> Are you eligible to work unrestricted in the country to which you are
>   applying?

I am applying for a job in japan, but do not currently have a work visa.
I don't believe there would be any hindrance to getting a work visa with an offer of employment.

How do I answer this question? Can I answer this question yes, even if I do not have a current work visa and will require sponsorship for one before starting employment?

EDIT: It's a yes or no question. It doesn't give me the opportunity to explain. They also have a separate Yes/No question for visa sponsorship.

I think I asked this question wrong. This application form is for a multinational company. These questions are likely the same no matter which country is being applied to.

Is this question really asking if I have all of the requirements to work unrestricted currently? Or is it more looking for whether I have anything practically preventing me from working there.

Comment: It's not what you believe that matters but what's actually going on. You need to get in touch with the Japanese Embassy or one of its consulates, and explain your situation. They can offer you the requisite guidance. You can't afford the penalty for getting the answer wrong. Also, review the expats' forums and ask questions there for good measure.

Comment: How certain are you of how long it would take to get a work visa? I know that in the US if you require an H1-B visa there is a cap that may prevent people from entering and other kinds of visas may be at the discretion of an immigration officer so beware of what you assume here.

Answer (score 10):

I would answer "I am not a Japanese citizen, nor do I currently hold a work visa for Japan."

Do NOT answer "YES" if you are not, right that second, eligible to work in Japan. You could potentially get into a LOT more trouble if the company interviews you and several other candidates, tenders you an offer, THEN finds out...oh, wait, you mean we have to help this person get a visa??? (As opposed to them knowing ahead of time that they may need to help you get a visa, even if the process goes super-smoothly.)

Don't set potential employers up to be blindsided.

Comment: Agreed, NEVER surprise HR (unless it's with cupcakes, HR loves cupcakes) It doesn't matter drugs, criminal record, employability, or any other relevant matter it's better to have it all out there and accurate than for them to find out later and question your trust worthiness. (Because we always assume the worst possible scenario when we find out ourselves, instead of if you provide it)

Comment: It's a yes or no question though. I don't want to be filtered out unnecessarily.

Comment: But if you answered "yes" when you are not in fact eligible to work in Japan, you would be lying. Because what happens if the Japanese government suddenly decides, we're not giving out any more work visas this year? What if you can't get a visa by the agreed-upon start date? Do NOT overpromise and underdeliver. It will always catch up with you.

Comment: Perhaps I will try to email their HR department. whats the worst that could happen.

Comment: Note: they have a seperate question asking if I required visa sponsorship.

Comment: Well then, there you go: answer "NO" to "are you currently eligible to work in the country; answer "YES" to "do you require visa sponsorship"; and email HR (and add a note to your resume) with more details/info about your current visa status and plans.

Comment: You don't think it's possible they simply ignore all the resumes with the answer 'No' and assume they are completely ineligible to work there?

Comment: It's possible that some companies disregard any resumes from ppl who require visa sponsorship (and if that's the case, many will state that on their sites/employment applications). But lying about your legal work status is never a good idea. If you're that concerned about missing out on job opportunities, go get your work visa, apply for jobs and THEN you can answer "yes" to the question of work eligibility in Japan. Or talk to the Japanese consulate and ask for their assistance in what notes to add, if your visa is in process.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've concluded that this question is meant as a politically correct way of asking whether or not you currently have a visa or citizenship... rather than a way of asking "are you banished" or similar. I will answer 'No'.

Comment: @user606723 Depending on the country, there may be a lot of different ways of being authorized to work. For example, (http://www.edd.ca.gov/pdf_pub_ctr/de8401.pdf) Lists A and C describe the documents that demonstrate authorization to work in the USA. The employer just wants to know if **any** of them applies to the applicant, not specifically whether they have a visa or citizenship.